# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request SqlException

Tags: sql, visual-studio, api

**When I create a new project (web api) in Visual Studio 2019, I try running the project but I got the following error:**

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: Invalid object name 'Books'.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__169_0(Task result)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you check spelling in `SqlDataReader`? For me, I was misspelled. If the spelling is correct, any chance are you re-using the same name of an existing environmental variable for a different database on the same SQL Server? If the answer is yes it can be issue too.